# Calling properties of one class into another class

Tags: c#

I have two classes like below and I want to use InvoiceItem properties at Invoice class and add to AddInvoiceItem method but I receive error.

```
   public class InvoiceItem
    {
        public int InvoiceItemId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public double Cost { get; set; }
    }

public class Invoice
    {
        public int InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
        public List<InvoiceItem> LineItems { get; set; }

        public void AddInvoiceItem(InvoiceItem invoiceItem)
        {
            LineItems.Add(invoiceItem);
        }
```

Comment: Please post the error message in full

Comment: In all cases, focus on and research the actual error message you are given.  Yours certainly does not mention calling class properties into another class in any way.

Answer (score 2):

From the little you've shown, most likely you haven't actually created your list.

Try

`public List<InvoiceItem> LineItems { get; set; } = new List<InvoiceItem>();`